# How to resolve redirection issue after Deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-cloud, web-deployment

I have created a spring boot application and uploaded it on IBM Cloud git repo. When i build the project and deploy only 1st page is showing. I can not redirect to any other page. How can i fix it.

application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/

#spring.application.name=dutchman

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

manifest.yml file

```
---
applications:
- instances: 1
  timeout: 600
  name: dutchman
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  path: ./target/javaspringapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  memory: 256M
  domain: eu-gb.cf.appdomain.cloud
  host: dutchman
  random-route: false
  env:
    JAVA_OPTS: '-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=32M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=32M'
    JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '[memory_calculator: {stack_threads: 30}]'
```

Comment: That looks like a Cloud Foundry manifest. Add more details on how you deploy it and the type of app

Comment: I am deploying it using ibm git and the app is purely spring boot